# How do I kick someone in cube2 Sauerbraten

Tags: linux, cube-2-sauerbraten

I play cube2 sauerbraten.  I was working on a map with some freinds, when this creep came and began to ruin my map making the sky pink and messing stuff up.  He comes on every time I go on.  Is there a way I can kick him??  I looked around, and found the sauerbraten documentation. I found nothing there that helped.  I need an answer that works, or my parents won't let me play at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a server, the fist person who wants to may claim master by typing `/setmaster B`.  If you are that person, you can type `/kick playername`.  Replace `playername` with the name of the guy you want to kick.